# Getting ticked header values using formula in Google sheets or excel

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table where I need to get the values of the ticked headers as shown. The ALL takes precedence and it will include all headers when ticked.

[Here is the working copy of the sheet.,](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uhVqSDtb-BJfrai8nUEsPQJdA7bJAtJW9a8phzRUgO4/edit?usp=sharing)

The expected values are shown in the image below.

The purple cells will have formula, H2, H3 and so for for each row.

[image]
I have tried with

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Config!A$1:A$16,(INDEX(Config!A$1:G$16,,MATCH(2,Config!$A$1:$1,0) ))=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Guy, see if this formula (need to drag down) does what you want:

```
=IF(B2,{C$1:F$1},IFERROR(FILTER(C$1:F$1,C2:F2),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Unlike @ttarchala's answer, I haven't come up with an array formula solution!

Comment: To briefly explain the formula used in this solution I will add that it uses a simple [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function that when ```B``` is selected (in the first case ```B2``` for the rest rows just drag and drop this formula) it returns all the cell values from ```C``` to ```F``` (as described [in the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) backets allow you to group together values keeping their order).

Comment: If not selected it uses an [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) function to display a blank cell if the filter function fails to return something. This [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function will return only the values checked (set to true) from ```C``` to ```F```. In that way when selected ```ALL``` everything will be displayed in order and when unticked it will show only those values ticked.

Answer (score 3):

delete H:K range and use in H2:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:B=TRUE, C1:F1&"♦", 
 IF(C2:F=TRUE, C1:F1&"♦", ))),,9^9)), "♦")))
```

[image]

Comment: ALL should not be displayed, Please note that ALL when sleected it would display the SORT, Quick Task Communication and Tools.

Answer (score 1):

"Brute-forcing" the solution with IFs kinda works, even though it's inelegant and not scalable to larger number of columns. Might be interesting to re-ask the question with an arbitrary number of columns. Pure formula solution might not be possible.

[image]